# Polymer 1.0 custom events

Tags: events, polymer

I was using this code on Polymer 0.5 but on Polymer 1.0 it's not working.

On child element:

```
this.fire('login-start', {
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password,
    me: this
});
```

On parent element (app-main.html):

```
<dom-module name="app-main" on-login-start="{{checkLogin}}">
```

And on app-main.js:

```
checkLogin: function() {
    alert("This is not working.");
}
```

How do I fire and catch custom events in Polymer 1.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should remove the double brackets `({{}})` from on-login-start.

```
<dom-module name="app-main" on-login-start="checkLogin">
```

[Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#declarative-handlers) is the documentation.